# How to prevent csv sniffer from thinking hyphen is UNICODE 8722 instead of 45?

Tags: python, csv

I am working on this thing that will try to figure out csv formatting and ask the end user if it's correct. I started testing with timezones and my test input looks like this.

```
            "\r\n".join(
                (
                    "timestamp;col1;col2",
                    "2020-01-22T00:14:47-04:00;1;6.1",
                    "2020-02-23T01:15:47-04:00;2;7.1",
                    "2020-02-24T01:15:47-04:00;3;8.1",
                    "2020-02-25T01:15:47-04:00;4;9.1",
                    "2020-02-26T01:15:47-04:00;5;0.",
                )
            ).encode()
```

To figure out dialect I do

```
csv.Sniffer().sniff(lookup_row, self.allowed_delimiters)
```

I load this file with

```
csv.reader(opened_csv, dialect=dialect)
```

Here's the fun part. When I copy-paste the first timestamp and `parse` it to datetime

```
from dateutil import parser

a = '2020-01-22T00:14:47-04:00'
found_val = parser.parse(a)
```

it properly returns the datetime. But when I run this input through sniff, csv.reader and iterate over rows in my test `dateutil` can't parse it

```
b = '2020-01-22T00:14:47−04:00'  # <-- in my test case
```

and

```
a == b
>>> False
```

So when I looked closer

```
a_ord = [ord(char) for char in a]  # [50, 48, 50, 48, 45, 48, 49, 45, 50, 50, 84, 48, 48, 58, 49, 52, 58, 52, 55, 45, 48, 52, 58, 48, 48]
b_ord = [ord(char) for char in b]  # [50, 48, 50, 48, 45, 48, 49, 45, 50, 50, 84, 48, 48, 58, 49, 52, 58, 52, 55, 8722, 48, 52, 58, 48, 48]
```

The diff is `-` sign near timezone. Apparently "raw" copy-paste results in minus which is UNICODE `45` while `sniffer` thinks (?) it's `8722`.

My mind is blown, especially because the rest of the hyphens in this cell are considered to be `45`.

As it's a special case scenario and I care only about the proper parsing of this column, is replacing this character (if found) the best way to go about that?

Or can I somehow define in sniffer that's a wrong character/limit UNICODE scope?

Should it be considered a bug in `dateutil`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. How are you opening your csv file? Why are you encoding your test data to a bytes object?

Comment: That's the raw input I get from the API and save it to `FileField` in Django. To load it I open payload with `rb`, decode and write to `StringIO`. Then use `csv.reader` with a sniffed dialect.

Comment: Strange. Using your test input -> encode -> decode -> put in StringIO -> sniff -> csv.reader I get the normal `-`. Also, I haven't heard of a csv reader or sniffer changing the **content** of csv **cells**. Probably something else is changing your dates. e.g. Django.

Comment: I don't think it's Django but I don't know what is. Anyway, I really appreciate you were digging into this.

Comment: @Wups I copied the timezone from a website with offset per timezone and there was this weird hyphen! You were right. Nothing has changed the enoding. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

> Should it be considered a bug in dateutil?

I wouldn't say that. I don't know anything about dateutil, but I'd say you just aren't taking advantage of the features available to you.

Looking at the documentation for [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse), it looks like you can pass an optional [dateutil.parser.parserinfo](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo) object that describes what constitutes acceptable input.

Specifically, I think you'll want to look at [dateutil.parser.parserinfo.JUMP](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parserinfo.JUMP), which seems to be a list of acceptable separators, which looks like this by default:

```
JUMP= [' ', '.', ',', ';', '-', '/', "'", 'at', 'on', 'and', 'ad', 'm', 't', 'of', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th']
```

So, I'm guessing, all you have to do is pass in one of these `parserinfo` objects with a custom `JUMP` that includes your special hyphen.

Comment: I wanted to make it parsable at the read level as I didn't want to replace characters in millions of cells one by one but for some reason, I haven't thought about just adding this weird char to `parserinfo`. Will try it now. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work as expected. ```b = '2020-01-22T00:14:47−04:00'  # <-- in my test case
pi = parserinfo
pi.JUMP.append(chr(8722))
dt = parser.parse(b, parserinfo=pi())``` returns `2020-01-22 04:00:00`

Comment: @TomWojcik What was the expected result? Sorry it's not clear to me.

Comment: `2020-01-22 00:14:47`. now it considers offset to be the `time` in my `datetime` object